# Display hashmap values in HTML dropdown box

Tags: java, drop-down-menu, hashmap

How to display hashmap values in an HTML dropdown box using Java?

```
HashMap<Integer,String> hm =new HashMap<Integer,String>();
hm.put(1,"abc");
hm.put(2,"def");
hm.put(3,"ghi");
```

Using the jEasyUI framework with jQuery.

Comment: Set<String> str= hm.KeySet();
how to show these values in dropdown ?

Comment: what's confusing here is mostly the accepted answer. it has nothing to do with jquery or jeasyui.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<%
    HashMap<Integer,String> hm =new HashMap<Integer,String>();
    hm.put(1,"abc");
    hm.put(2,"def");
    hm.put(3,"ghi");

     for(int i=1;i<hm.size();i++){
%>
      <option value="<%= i%>"><%= hm.get(i) %></option>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list returned from hm.values()

Answer (score 0):

Take a for loop and build options like below

```
"<option value="+hm.getKey()+">"+hm.getValue()+"</option>";
```

[HashMap doc.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)