# Javascript hashmap values displayed by a HTML dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary, hashmap

Is there a way to put JS hashmap values into a HTML dropdown box?

[Display hashmap values in HTML dropdown box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22912859/display-hashmap-values-in-html-dropdown-box) This didnt work.

```
    var x = new Map
    x.put("Name", number).put("Name", number)...
```

and then display this in

```
     <select id="select">
        <option value="default">**Map values here**</option>
    </select>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the `map` using `forEach` and dynamically create `option` to append it to the select

```js
var x = new Map();
x.set('bar', 'foo')
  .set('bar1', 'foo1')
  .set('bar2', 'foo2')
  .set('bar3', 'foo3')
  .set('bar4', 'foo4');
let z = '';
x.forEach(function(item) {
  let o = document.createElement('option');
  o.innerHTML = item;
  document.getElementById('select').appendChild(o)

});
```

```html
<select id="select">
  <option value="default">**Map values here**</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It works on stack but in my IDE Im getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null"

Comment: I had my script tags in the wrong place my mistake thanks for the help!